# Suspend the work on a git branch and work on another (mainly locally)

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I have to work on different little features and I usually save them locally with `git stash save "feature name"`.

I read that [using branches has more sense](http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/git-stash-pop-considered-harmful/), and I believe it could be true, cause a branch allows you to keep also untracked files (while with *stash* I have to remember to add the *-u* parameter to keep them). And you also have the option to *git push* it on the remote repository.

So, from an initial clean *master* branch, I created a new **local** branch, with `git checkout -b feature_name`, and made some changes, created new files, etc.

#### Now...

1. I would like to **pause my incomplete work** (so I would not commit anything, even if local, cause it has not sense to me) and have it available for keep **working on it later**.
2. Then I would like to **switch back to a clean branch** (master, where I was starting from) and **create a new one** for a second feature

But if I `git checkout master` or `git checkout -b new_feature_2` I get all the the changes from the first feature branch merged into the branch I'm switching to.

Can someone explain me:

- Why that? Are not **branches** supposed to be something **'divided' each from the others** (so I can work on different things at the same time)? Or **does that division exist JUST if I proceed with a commit in the branches?**
- Is there a way to **switch to a branch without merging** the working directory? And, does it have sense, in the Git logic?

Should I keep using *stashes* to do what I desire? (having different local working directories and switch between them, without committing to the repository).

My question is because **I DON'T LIKE TO COMMIT!** :)
Or, I mean, it has sense to me to *commit just the meaningful changes*.

I don't want the history to have commits with incomplete work, or not tested code, or anything that is not definitive.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, branches can be at two different places in time.

first make sure that you have pushed to github, and have a master branch created.
To do this:

```
git branch
```

It should show you a master branch. 
If not, please follow the [instructions here.](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line)

**to create a new branch** you do:

```
git checkout -b new_feature_branch
```

you will now be on the **new_feature_branch**. You can now create any changes you would like and they will exist only on **new_feature_branch**.

Once you have made the changes, you must commit them to the branch.

First **add the new files:**

```
git add .
```

This adds all unstaged files.

Then, **commit the files:**

```
git commit -a -m "enter a commit message here, explaining what you did"
```

Now you can switch back to master and work without the changes you made.

```
git checkout master
```

*Note that you can save changes for later without commiting them with stash. You just need to do "git stash" to hide the changes for a time. and "git stash pop" to bring them back. This is not a safe or as powerful as branching*

Comment: Thank you for writing the procedure.
What I was referring too was to work **locally** with branches (as I do usually with stashes).
My aim is to have all the dirty process and commits on my laptop, **without pushing** anything to GitHub.
Sorry, my fault I didn't write it.

Comment: By the way, my answer was not about how to use branches or stashes. I already know the commands for that, and I use them regularly.
I'm interested in the particular use of those, as described in my question. I edited it; hope it's clearer now.